# Get Python socket data with Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, sockets

So suppose I have the following server running on python

```py
import time
import socket


HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 65432

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    s.listen()
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    with conn:
        while True:
            timer = random.randint(1,3)
            value = random.randrange(999)
            time.sleep(timer)
            conn.sendall(str(f"Slept {timer} seconds. Value: {value}").encode())
```

As you can see, this will sleep for a random time and send data. Now I want to fetch these values with javascript and show those on a webpage. But since the data comes realtime, I cannot use the `fetch` method in JS.

I've read about websocket but I don't want to use it since there will be only one client connected and that too will just receive data and will not send any.

Is there any way I can do this without using any external modules? Thank you

Comment: First it accepts a connection, and *then* it periodically sends data on *that* connection. Unless you're the connected peer you can't receive anything.

Comment: Can I do this with client-side javascript? (I mean without using node.js)

Comment: If you mean with *"fetch these values with javascript and show those on a webpage"* to use Javascript inside the browser, then you will not be able to use plain TCP sockets. You either need to use Websockets or HTTP requests. Both can be done without external modules but it gets  complicated. Modules are not magic, they are just to make it easier since the complex work was already done.

Comment: Why not flip it around? Have js client to the sleeping and request the data periodically from the python server.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp  I can't. Because in the real project, I'll call some other function and when done, I'll be sending the info to the browser.

Comment: Then maybe you need to re-think about using web sockets. As you seem to know, js ajax/fetch connections are not meant to be kept open.

Comment: Alright. Thank you.